# Trouble with Jmeter Throughput Controller

Tags: jmeter

I am having trouble understanding exactly how the Jmeter Throughput Controller should work in relation to a Performance Test that I have been working on.

**Scenario 1:** Recreate production environment website traffic in a lower environment based off of the busiest day my business experienced last year.

**Scenario 2:** Recreate production environment website traffic in a lower environment based off of an average day of business.

The Test Plan is using a Constant Throughput Timer set to "This Thread Only". Target Throughput value is determined by which scenario is being tested, and the value is calculated using logs from production.

I have roughly two dozen samplers in the test, each managed by a Throughput Controller set to "Percent Executions". To figure out what the percentage of the Throughput Controller should be I am doing the following:

1. (Target Throughput value from Constant Throughput Controller) / 60 = A
2. (average rps of endpoint in sampler) / A x 100 = (Percentage for Throughput Controller)

This approach works for Scenario 1 and I am able to recreate my business' busiest day of traffic in terms of rps for each endpoint. However, this approach does NOT work for Scenario 2. In Scenario 2 what I am seeing is a rps that is almost the same for all the endpoints, despite some samplers having a 100% Throughput Controller percentage and others having as low as 1%.

What is flawed in this approach? And why would it work for the higher load scenario and not the lower one?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve different throughput for different Samplers within the bounds of a single Thread Group because JMeter waits for the previous sampler to complete before starting the new one therefore all the Samplers will be running at the speed of the "slowest" sampler.

Also be aware of [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), depending on the location of the timer it might be applied to one, several or all Samplers

Also Constant Throughput Timer is:

- precise enough on "minute" level
- can only pause the thread(s) to limit JMeter's load to the given value

so you either need to play with ramp-up or considering switching to [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

If you need to run different Samplers with different throughput you will have to switch to separate [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

Comment: "You won't be able to achieve different throughput for different Samplers within the bounds of a single Thread Group because JMeter waits for the previous sampler to complete before starting the new one therefore all the Samplers will be running at the speed of the "slowest" sampler."   This is not what I am seeing when I do my Scenario 1 testing. In this scenario I am seeing my percentages set in Throughput Controllers reflected correctly. All of these Samplers are in the same Thread Group. why would it work for this scenario but not the lower volume one?